# how to count one dot as a zero in QlineEdit pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Currently I'm Creating a program application that tallies the total numbers entered via QlineEdit, I recently encountered a problem where when I entered multiple . (dots) it will count nothing or error is and I'm using the QRegExpValidator whereas my RegExp is  `QRegExp('^[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]$')` which detects numbers that has 2 decimal places in it now I want to do is when I entered only a dot it will count only zero or the QlineEdit will not allow only 1 dot and no numbers. thanks in advance

Comment: Note that you could use a [QDoubleSpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html) or [QDoubleValidator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublevalidator.html) for the QLineEdit. That said, just use a `try/except` block: `try: value = float(text)` `except: value = 0`.

Comment: I just resolved it yesterday by adding 0 in the input since it will not affect the value when checking thank you for suggestions